# CURL does not give full html contents

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to parse a shopping site webpage using CURL in PHP.
the url is: http://computers.pricegrabber.com/printers/HP-Officejet-Pro-8600-Plus-All-One-Wireless-Inkjet-Printer/m916995235.html/zip_code=97045/sort_type=bottomline

Here's the code I use.

```
function getWebsiteCURL($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $output;
}

echo getWebsiteCURL("http://computers.pricegrabber.com/printers/HP-Officejet-Pro-8600-Plus-All-One-Wireless-Inkjet-Printer/m916995235.html/zip_code=97045/sort_type=bottomline");
```

It works, but I couldn't get the full HTML code.

Anybody have any idea why?
TIA.

Comment: The page use Javascript. Anything added by the scripts won't be visible with cURL.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the full contents?

Comment: You'll need to run a Javascript interpreter, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by connection timeout.

Try setting the opt:

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 120

Answer (score 0):

curl cannot interpret Javascript, you can see what curl will see if you disable javascript in a browser and navigate to the page. If you need to interpret Javascript then I would use a headless browser like phantomjs. In PHP you could use [PHP PhantomJS](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/).